# Extract Tar.gz files from Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am newbie to Google cloud,need to extract the files with extension "xxxx.tar.gz" in cloud storage and load into BiQuery(multiple files to multiple tables)

I tried the cloud function with nodejs using npm modules like "tar.gz" and "jaguar",both didn't work.

can someone share some inputs to decompress the files using other languages like python or Go also.

**my work**: so far I decompressed files manually copied to that target bucket and loaded to bigquery using background functions using nodejs

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

tar is a Linux tool for archiving a group of files together - e.g., see [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) manual page. You can unpack a compressed tar file using a command like:

```
tar xfz file.tar.gz
```

Comment: To expand on what Mike said, .tar.gz is not actually "double compressed" since a tar archive is not inherently compressed (thus the additional layer of gzip application is commonly applied).

Comment: Thanks Mike, I am currently doing this manually and copying to another bucket where I am using background function based on gcs trigger event.

Answer (score 0):

Mike is right wrt. tar archives. Regarding the second half of the question in the title, Cloud Storage does not natively support unpacking a tar archive. You'd have to do this yourself (on your local machine or from a Compute Engine VM, for instance)

Comment: Thanks lot, but I need help with cloud function using modules like tar.gz, jaguar to extract the files. can someone share a piece of code to startwith or sources of the code.